# Install a specific dependency using NSIS zip folder

Tags: python, windows, nsis, ghostscript

So my project is python-based, and I have already created the .exe file for it using `pyinstaller`.

Now I have a folder containing,

- `main.exe` file
- `README.txt`

I am able to make a single executable file, that will install the dependencies related to main.exe, using `NSIS`. But for my project to run properly, I need to install another software called [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html).

I was wondering if there is a way to do so in NSIS itself. Like when it installs the dependencies it automatically installs `GhostScript` too.

**NOTE: It's for a Windows app**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostscript [also uses NSIS](https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Install.htm#Install_Windows) so it supports the same silent install switch as other NSIS installers.

```
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
RequestExecutionLevel Admin

Page Components
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

!include LogicLib.nsh

Section "Ghostscript"
InitPluginsDir
File "/oname=$pluginsdir\gsinst.exe" "gs9540w32.exe"
ExecWait '"$pluginsdir\gsinst.exe" /S' $0
${If} $0 <> 0
  MessageBox mb_iconstop "Unable to install Ghostscript!"
  Abort
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File main.exe
File Readme.txt
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you so much.